# "IndexError: too many indices for array" while merging VIPERS and PRIMUS

Tags: python, numpy, astropy, fits

Hi I'm trying to extract RA, Dec and redshift information from the two surveys(PRIMUS and VIPERS) and collects them into a single nd-array.
The code is as follows :

```
from astropy.io import fits
import numpy as np

hdulist_PRIMUS = fits.open('data/PRIMUS_2013_zcat_v1.fits')

data_PRIMUS = hdulist_PRIMUS[1].data
data_PRIMUS = np.column_stack((data_PRIMUS['RA'], data_PRIMUS['DEC'],
    data_PRIMUS['Z'], data_PRIMUS['FIELD']))
data_PRIMUS = np.array(filter(lambda x: x[3].strip() == 'xmm', data_PRIMUS))[:, :3]
data_PRIMUS = np.array(map(lambda x: [float(x[0]), float(x[1]), float(x[2])], data_PRIMUS))

hdulist_VIPERS = fits.open('data/VIPERS_W1_SPECTRO_PDR2.fits')
data_VIPERS = hdulist_VIPERS[1].data
data_VIPERS = np.column_stack((data_VIPERS['alpha'], data_VIPERS['delta'], data_VIPERS['zspec']))

from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

PRIMUS_catalog = SkyCoord(ra=data_PRIMUS[:, 0]*u.degree, dec =data_PRIMUS[:, 1]*u.degree)
VIPERS_catalog = SkyCoord(ra=data_VIPERS[:, 0]*u.degree, dec=data_VIPERS [:, 1]*u.degree)

idx, d2d, d3d = PRIMUS_catalog.match_to_catalog_sky(VIPERS_catalog)
feasible_indices = np.array(map(
    lambda x: x[0],
    filter(lambda x: x[1].value > 1e-3, zip(idx, d2d))))
data_VIPERS = data_VIPERS[feasible_indices]
data_HZ = np.vstack((data_PRIMUS, data_VIPERS))
```

When I run this I'm getting a "IndexError: too many indices for array"

Datasets:
PRIMUS Redshift Catalog - https://primus.ucsd.edu/version1.html
VIPERS Redshift Catalog - https://projects.ift.uam-csic.es/skies-universes/VIPERS/photometry/

Comment: There's something weird going on with lots of superfluous spaces in your code formatting. Even the filenames have it, like `'data / PRIMUS_2013_zcat_v1 . fits '` which can't possibly be right. When you get an error message please also post the full traceback, as it will show exactly on what line the error is occurring. Will follow up later with a more substantive comment.

Comment: I went ahead and cleaned up most of the code formatting to use spaces in a more standard way.  Now I'll try to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few ways you're doing this where you're making it harder for yourself by not using existing, available tools effectively.  For example, since you are working with tabular data from a FITS file, you can take advantage of Astropy's [Table](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/) interface:

```
>>> from astropy.table import Table
>>> primus = Table.read('PRIMUS_2013_zcat_v1.fits')
```

(for this particular file I got some warnings about some of the headers in the table being non-standard, but this can be ignored).

If you want to do some operations on just a few columns of the table, you can do this easily.  For example, rather than doing what you did, of selecting a few columns together, and then stacking them into a new array

```
np.column_stack((data_PRIMUS['RA'], data_PRIMUS['DEC'],
data_PRIMUS['Z'], data_PRIMUS['FIELD']))
```

you can select a subset of columns from the table like so:

```
>>> primus[['RA', 'DEC', 'Z', 'FIELD']]
<Table length=213696>
        RA                 DEC             Z          FIELD    
      degree              degree                               
     float64             float64        float32      bytes13   
------------------ ------------------- ---------- -------------
52.892275339281994 -27.833172368069615  0.3420992 calib        
 52.88448889270391  -27.85252305560996  0.4824943 calib        
52.880363885710295  -27.86221750021335 0.33976158 calib        
 52.88334306466262  -27.86937808271639  0.6134631 calib        
  52.8866138857103 -27.871773055662942 0.58744365 calib        
52.885607068267845 -27.889578785511922 0.26873255 calib        
               ...                 ...        ...           ...
          34.54856             -4.5544  0.8544105 xmm          
          34.56942            -4.57564  0.6331108 xmm          
34.567412432719756  -4.572718190305209  1.1456184 xmm          
          34.57134            -4.56414  0.6346616 xmm          
          34.58088            -4.56804   1.081143 xmm          
          34.58686            -4.57449  0.7471819 xmm
```

Then it seems you select the `RA`, `DEC`, and `Z` columns where the field is `xmm` by using a `filter` function, but as these are Numpy arrays you can use the filtering capabilities built into Numpy array indexing, as well as Table indexing.  The only tricky part is that since these are fixed width character fields you do still need to perform comparisons correctly.  You can use Numpy's string functions like [`np.char.startswith`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.char.startswith.html#numpy.char.startswith) for this:

```
>>> primus = primus[np.char.startswith(primus['FIELD'], b'xmm')]
```

In the process of doing a performance comparison, I realized this line is where you're probably getting the error `IndexError: too many indices for array`:

```
>>> np.array(filter(lambda x: x[3].strip() == 'xmm', primus))
array(<filter object at 0x7f5170981940>, dtype=object)
```

In Python 3, the `filter` function returns an iterable, so wrapping it in `np.array()` just makes a 0-D array containing this Python object; it's probably not what you intended, so it fails here (this is where looking at the traceback might have been useful).  Even if you wrapped the `filter()` call in `list()` it wouldn't work, because `np.array()` only takes homogeneous arrays normally.  So an approach like the one I gave is perfectly sufficient (though there may be slightly more efficient ways).  It also makes the next line:

```
np.array(map(lambda x: [float(x[0]), float(x[1]), float(x[2])], data_PRIMUS))
```

unnecessary.  In particular, the first three columns are already in floating point format so this would not be necessary anyways.

Some similar advice applies to the other parts of your code.  I'd have written it like more like this:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.table import Table, vstack
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

primus = Table.read('PRIMUS_2013_zcat_v1.fits')
primus_field = primus['FIELD']
primus = primus[['RA', 'DEC', 'Z']]
primus = primus[np.char.startswith(primus_field, b'xmm')]
vipers = Table.read('VIPERS_W1_SPECTRO_PDR2.fits')[['alpha', 'delta', 'zspec']]

primus_catalog = SkyCoord(ra=primus['RA']*u.degree, dec=primus['DEC']*u.degree)
vipers_catalog = SkyCoord(ra=vipers['alpha']*u.degree, dec=vipers['delta']*u.degree)
idx, d2d, d3d = primus_catalog.match_to_catalog_sky(vipers_catalog)
feasible_indices = idx[d2d > 1e-3]
vipers = vipers[feasible_indices]
vipers.rename_columns(['alpha', 'delta', 'zspec'], ['RA', 'DEC', 'Z'])
hz = vstack(primus, vipers)
```

Please let me know if there are any parts of this you have questions on.